# Laravel select2 how to update each selected option id Model

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-select2

I have a simple select2 dropdown with foreach from database that retrieves my Model's id:

```
["3219","3220"]
```

I want foreach selected id to update the Model with the input value in the form

My form looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
          
          <input hidden type="text" value="{{$invoices->id}}" name="invoice_id" id="">
         
          
          <label for="">Colete neasociate</label>
<select name="id[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control js-example-basic-single" id="">
  <option value=""></option>
  @foreach ($coletes as $coletes)
      <option value="{{$coletes->id}}"> Coletul {{$coletes->ID}} cu nr {{$coletes->numarcursa}} </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

In my controller I've tried:

```
$colete = $request->input('id');

foreach($colete as $row){
    $colete = colete::find($row['id']);
    $colete->invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;
    $colete->save();
}
```

But it returns me this error:

```
Cannot access offset of type string on string
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your foreach needs some work. you are assigning the looping variable to the same name as the collection. Also can you please send your whole controller function? You also use id and ID. Another thing is you pass into the name attribute on the select as id[]. Not sure what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Also utilize laravel's ORM Eloquent. Don't unless you have a reason do things like ```$colete->invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;``` There is a lot here to discuss. Even the HTML.

Comment: I am sorry, basically I have 2 models, Invoices and coletes(coletes are the packages of the invoice) I am trying to link the coletes to the correct invoice by giving each selected colete id the invoice_id.

Comment: I don't want to sound like a jerk but I would recommend reading laravels docs on relationships, controllers, naming conventions, and blade templates.

Comment: try dd, dump every step

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to print the result of $request->input('id'), to see if the array has the key 'id'.

In the meantime you can remove the "id" key from $row to see if it works

https://onlinephp.io/c/2ded5

```
$colete = colete::find($row);
```

As a suggestion, I recommend you to rename the "$colete" variable in the foreach structure.

```
$colete_free = Colete::find($row);
$colete_free->invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;
$colete_free->save();
```

Comment: I think it would be better if he used the orm instead of storing the invoice_id. `$coleteFree->invoice()->save(Invoice::find($validatedDate['invoice_id']));`